# How parsing xml from url get attribute javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, parsing

I need parsing xml from url [url xml](https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?exchange&coursid=3)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<exchangerates>
  <row>
    <exchangerate ccy="RUR" base_ccy="UAH" buy="0.33291" sale="0.33291"/>
  </row>
  <row>
    <exchangerate ccy="EUR" base_ccy="UAH" buy="18.60253" sale="18.60253"/>
  </row>
  <row>
    <exchangerate ccy="USD" base_ccy="UAH" buy="14.97306" sale="14.97306"/>
  </row>
</exchangerates>
```

I whant get attribute for using "14.97306" to convert my currency

```
(like mycurrency = 10 )
(like usd = 14.97306 )
(mycurrency * usd = 149.7306)
```

Comment: What programming language do you plan to use for it?

Comment: javascript, it`s will be web page.

Comment: Than you should remove JAVA tag :)
The answer bellow from geert3 is for JAVA

Comment: @AndreyE - and the subject title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rudimentary setup for Java. You'll need to read up on XPATH queries, and you need to add exception handling etc. But I'm sure this will get you started.

```
    // open the URL
    URL url = ....
    InputStream is = url.openStream();

    // build a document parser
    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    // parse the document from the URL
    Document d = builder.parse(is);

    // set up XPATH to examine/query the XML
    XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();

    // use XPATH query to find the required information
    String sale = xpath.evaluate("/exchangerates/row[@ccy='USD']/@sale", d);

    System.out.println("USD sale is "+sale);
```

Comment: where this code must parsing info, I have white page =( I know java very bad sorry

Comment: Sorry chap. I can offer some food but chewing and swallowing is up to you.

Comment: that's the spirit ;-)